# Product price as per weekdays in Magento 2

Tags: product, magento2.3, orders, price, customize

If I need to change product price based on week days what is the efficient way for this?

Like product is a booking entity (like flight ticket) & every Wednesday & friday amount of product is higher than usual.
Customer can book it for future so price will show & calculate accordingly.

Comment: I would go for registering custom catalog rule condition

Comment: @Roman Catalogue rule will not increase product price as they are used to give discount.